# Ultisnips not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am a newbie in latex. I tried to install Ultisnips for reducing frustration. I installed it using vim-plug. However, it isn't working for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
  set number

   " Call the .vimrc.plug file"
    if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.plug"))
        source ~/.vimrc.plug
    endif
```

And here is `/.vimrc.plug` file:

```
   call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

   "Fugitive Vim Github Wrapper
   Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
   let g:tex_flavor='latex'
   let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
   let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
   set conceallevel=1
   let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'


  Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
  let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
  let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = ['~/.vim/UltiSnips/' , 'Ultisnips']
  let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
  let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'
  let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
  call plug#end()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.vimrc` I noticed a few things that are wrong.

First of all
On line 12, The way to install Ultisnips using `Plug` is

> Plug 'sirVir/ultisnips'

and not `'sirvir/ultisnips'`after that just install the plugin using `:PlugInstall` in the command mode.

By default in Ubuntu it creates a directory under `~/UltiSnips` for your custom snippets (or you can check for yourself which directory is UltiSnips using on your machine by `:UltiSnipsEdit` and change the following line).

> let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['~/UltiSnips']

Comment: Something was definitely wrong, cause it started working after I reinstalled it. And the same `sirvir/ultisnips` worked.

Comment: Oh! glad it worked for you, But I saw `sirvir/ultisnips` is for Vundle users and `sirVir/ultisnips` is for Plug users.